# Complete Regex syntax for Sql Server Management Studio

Tags: regex, ssms, replace

Is there a complete description of the regular expression syntax used in Sql Server Management Studio?  There must be a way to do negative lookaheads, for example, but the find/replace dialog doesn't list one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

SSMS versions 2005-2012 are really just modified/customized Visual Studio Shell (2005-2010) environments, so this Visual Studio (2005-2010) Regular Expression reference applies:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2k3te2cs(v=vs.80).aspx

Visual Studio 2012 and later have switched to standard .Net regular expressions.

However SSMS did not follow suit and adapt standard regular expressions until SSMS 2016.

Comment: In know this is an old post, but this answer is wrong for Visual Studio 2012 and newer.  The regular expressions in SSMS are no longer the same as those in Visual Studio.  (Visual Studio dumped it's quirky dialect for a much more standard implementation.  SSMS did not.)  I have posted an answer relevant to recent versions of SSMS.

Comment: Thanks @SvdSinner, updated the answer to more accurately reflect the ongoing evolution of VS shells. If you happen to know what the story is with SSMS 2014 please edit the answer or leave another comment so I can fix!

Comment: SSMS 2014 still uses the old quirky implementation. No idea for SSMS 2016.

Answer (score 6):

SSMS uses a qurky RegEx implementation that is *very* different from what is used in Visual Studio and in the .NET Regex class.

A complete list if its capabilities and their corresponding syntax can be found [here at MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174214.aspx).

Even with the documentation to its bizarre dialect of regular expressions, you may find its feature set quite lacking.  (Examples: It doesn't support basics like the "?" operator or useful advanced things like positive look around.)  You can do negative look arounds with this syntax:

> ```
> Prevent match    ~(X)    Prevents a match when X appears at this point in the
>                          expression. For example, real~(ity) matches the "real" 
>                          in "realty" and "really," but not the "real" in "reality."
> ```

The only benefit I've seen of the quirky SSMS dialect is that it does contain a lot of built-in character classes not seen in many other engines.
Examples:

> ```
> Math symbol       :Sm   Matches +, =, ~, |, <, and >.
> Currency symbol   :Sc   Matches $ and other currency symbols.
> ```

#### NOTE FOR THOSE WHO ALREADY USE REGULAR EXPRESSIONS ELSEWHERE:

Realistically, unless you intend on making a LOT of usage of the custom groups it contains, it probably will not be worth your time to learn this bizarre dialect of Regex.  Copy your query over to an editor with a more standard implementation (visual studio 2012 or later, notepad++, etc.) and you will be better served.