# BigQuery REGEXP_REPLACE referencing capture group in the replacement expression

Tags: google-bigquery, regexp-replace, capture-group

I'm very new to Regex so this may seem a very dumb question.

I've been playing around with captured groups in Google Sheets, without any problems, but when I try and apply it to BigQuery, it doesn't seem to work and I can't find out how to implement the syntax.

I looked round and this seems to be the closest answer, but I can't make it work:
[Find and replace using regular expression, group capturing, and back referencing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31296632/find-and-replace-using-regular-expression-group-capturing-and-back-referencing)

I want to reference a capture group in the replacement expression to either extract or replace `£ 1,000.23` in this text:

`random text £ 1,000.23 other text`

I've got 3 groups:
`(.+)`
`(£\ *[\d\.\,]+)`
`(.+)`

It may not be the best example, but I really want to understand how to use a capture group in the replacement part so I'm not looking for an alternative solution.

The code below literally returns '$2' rather than '£ 1,000.23'.

```
SELECT
  note,
  REGEXP_REPLACE(note,r'(.+)(£\ *[\d\.\,]+)(.+)','$2') AS note2
FROM
  `project.dataset.table`
LIMIT
  100
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the replacement note in the [doc](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/string_functions#regexp_replace), I think the following should work:

```
SELECT
  note,
  REGEXP_REPLACE(note,r'(.+)(£\ *[\d\.\,]+)(.+)','\\2') AS note2
FROM
  `project.dataset.table`
LIMIT
  100
```